# Sencha Touch 2.4.2 chart line series - line not drawn fully

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am having an issue on iPads in landscape mode. This does not happen on Android tablets.

As you can see from the images, the line does not get displayed fully in landscape mode:

**Portrait**

[image: Portrait]

**Landscape**

[image: Landscape]

Has anyone seen this issue and know how to solve it?